# Get nearest input element from same div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's say I have next construction

```
<table id="mainTable">
  <tr>
    <td>
       <div class="parentDiv">
         <input class="childInput"/>
         <table>
           <tbody>
           <tr>
             <td>
               <span>I am here!</span>
             <td>
           </tr>
           </tbody>
         </table>
       </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How can I get `input` element from `span`? Using jQuery or standart methods.
`mainTable` has many rows so I can't use `id` on input.
I can do it with:

```
$($(spanElement).parents(".parentDiv")[0]).children(".childInput")[0]
```

Do you know an easier way?

Comment: Read the [jQuery docs for Traversing](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$(spanElement).closest('.parentDiv').find('input');
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$(spanElement).closest('.parentDiv').find('.childInput');
```